# Problems in implementation of avl tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, nodes, avl-tree, insertion

I am trying to implement an avl tree but it gives incorrect result if the first 7 whole numbers are inserted into it. The heights of the nodes after insertion are-
node 0 - 0
node 1 - 1
node 2 - 2
node 3 - 3
node 4 - 1
node 5 - 1
node 6 - 0
The tree is not balanced at node 2. Here are the functions -

```
class AVLTree
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int val;
        node *left;
        node *right;
        node *parent;

        node(int val, node *parent)
        {
            this->val = val;
            this->parent = parent;
            this->left = nullptr;
            this->right = nullptr;
        }
    } *root;

    void rotate_left(node* a)
    {
        node *b = a->right;
        if (!b || (!b->left && !b->right))
        {
            return;
        }
        node *p = a->parent;
        if (p)
        {
            if (p->right == a)
            {
                p->right = b;
            }
            else
            {
                p->left = b;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            root = b;
        }
        b->parent = a->parent;
        a->right = b->left;
        b->left = a;
    }

    void rotate_right(node* c)
    {
        node* b = c->left;
        if (!b)
        {
            return;
        }
        node *p = c->parent;
        if (p->right == c)
        {
            p->right = b;
        }
        else
        {
            p->left = b;
        }
        c->left = b->right;
        b->right = c;
    }

    node* leftDescendent(node* n)
    {
        if (n->left == nullptr)
        {
            return n;
        }
        else
        {
            leftDescendent(n->left);
        }
    }

    node* rightAncestor(node* n)
    {
        if (n->val < n->parent->val)
        {
            return n->parent;
        }
        else
        {
            rightAncestor(n->parent);
        }
    }

    node* next(node* n)
    {
        if (n->right != nullptr)
        {
            return leftDescendent(n->right);
        }
        else
        {
            rightAncestor(n);
        }
    }

    void addHelper(node* root, int i)
    {
        if (root->val >= i)
        {
            if (root->left)
                addHelper(root->left, i);
            else
                root->left = new node(i, root);
        }
        else
        {
            if (root->right)
                addHelper(root->right, i);
            else
                root->right = new node(i, root);
        }
    }

    node* searchHelper(node *root, int val)
    {
        if (root == nullptr)
            return nullptr;
        else if (root->val == val)
            return root;
        else if (root->val > val)
            searchHelper(root->left, val);
        else if (root->val < val)
            searchHelper(root->right, val);
    }

    void rebalance_right(node* n)
    {
        node* m = n->left;
        if (!m)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (height(m->left) < height(m->right))
        {
            rotate_left(m);
        }
        rotate_right(n);
    }

    void rebalance_left(node* n)
    {
        node* m = n->right;
        if (!m)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (height(m->left) > height(m->right))
        {
            rotate_right(m);
        }
        rotate_left(n);
    }

    void rebalance(node* n)
    {
        node* p = n->parent;
        if (n->left || n->right)
        {
            if (height(n->left) > height(n->right) )
            {
                rebalance_right(n);
            }
            if (height(n->left) < height(n->right) )
            {
                rebalance_left(n);
            }
        }

        if (p)
        {
            rebalance(p);
        }
    }

    node* del(node* n)
    {
        if (n->right == nullptr && n->left == nullptr)
        {
            if (n->parent->left == n)
            {
                n->parent->left = nullptr;
            }
            else if (n->parent->right == n)
            {
                n->parent->right = nullptr;
            }
            node* p = n->parent;
            delete n;
            return p;
        }
        else if (n->right == nullptr)
        {
            node* nleft = n->left;
            n->parent->left = nleft;
            nleft->parent = n->parent;
            delete n;
            return nleft->parent;
        }
        else if (n->left == nullptr)
        {
            node* nright = n->right;
            n->parent->right = nright;
            nright->parent = n->parent;
            delete n;
            return nright->parent;
        }       
        else
        {
            node* nxt = next(n);
            n->val = nxt->val;
            del(nxt);
        }
    }

public:
    AVLTree()
    {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    int height(node* r)
    {
        if (!r)
            return -1;
        int left = height(r->left);
        int right = height(r->right);
        return (left > right ? left : right) + 1;
    }

    node* search(int val)
    {
        return searchHelper(root, val);
    }

    void add(int i)
    {
        if (root)
        {
            addHelper(root, i);
            rebalance(search(i)->parent);
        }
        else
            root = new node(i, nullptr);
    }

    void insert(int val)
    {
        add(val);
        node *n = search(val);
        rebalance(n);
    }

    void del(int n)
    {
        rebalance(del(search(n)));
    }
};

int main()
{
    AVLTree at;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        at.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " " <<  at.height(at.search(i)) << "\n";
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

function height returns -1 if node doesn't exist and 0 if it is a leaf node.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement an AVL tree?

Comment: I learning about trees right now

Comment: It's OK to learn but you should know that AVL trees usually have inferior performance compared to e.g. red-black trees. Almost nobody uses AVL in real software.

Comment: I know but it is a part of an online course and I need to implement it.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Then we can independently compile and solve.

Comment: Draw the actual tree before rebalance and after rebalance, and the expected tree after rebalance. Post pictures (ASCII art OK).